# Java REST API framework without Maven/Gradle

Tags: java, rest, http, frameworks

Can someone name me one mini framework in Java that will allow me to build a REST API? The thing is that all need maven installation or Gradle or something similar, but I need something that will "play" with a very simpler installation like installing just a jar or something similar.

Comment: _Why_ are you opposed to using Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Maven and Gradle are project management tools .Developers use them mostly to manage dependencies , but there is no any hard rule saying you must use it compulsory.So if you don't want to use them , you can neglect them ,but then as you asked you need to add all those JAR files externally by searching them through the internet or mostly in maven central repository.Best option would be spring boot application but if you don't like to use maven then I suggest you to go with Spring framework ,but then you should add all those JAR files manually.As an alternative JAX-RS + Jersy will also be fine .

Comment: Thanks for answering, yes I know it is just a project management tool , but I don't want anything like this for some reasons (useless to tell them here because it's time waste)

The thing is that all these frameworks have too many jars that is almost impossible to find them all.

Comment: If you don't like to use a dependency management tool then I don't see any option rather than adding those Jar files manually .Spring and the JAX-RS + Jersy are the most popular frameworks you can use for this task.

Comment: Can i ask something last? Is there any way to find all the JAR that a framework contains with an easy way maybe?

Comment: Yes you can search those JAR files in the Central maven repository .There are Zip files containing all the JAR files in an one folders so you can unzip and add all at once.